# Xcode 6.1.1 debugger fails to display values of a variable in the console. Why?

Tags: debugging, swift, xcode6gm

Why don't I see the values of a particular variable in the debugger?

Here's the data type:

```
struct hashTag {
    var parseID:String?
    var blguID:String
    var owner:String?
    var ownerImage:UIImage?
    var displayName:String?
    var tagDescription:String?
    var startTimeStamp:NSDate?
    var endTimeStamp:NSDate?
    var accessPermission:hashtagPermission = .greenUnlockPublic
    var geo:geoStatus?
    var coordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    var radiusInMeters:CGFloat?
    var duration:Int?
    var discoverableBy:[String]?
    init(blissID blugID:String, owner:String, ownerImage:UIImage, displayName:String, accessPermission:hashtagPermission, startTimeStamp:NSDate) {
        self.blguID = blugID
        self.owner = owner
        self.ownerImage = ownerImage
        self.displayName = displayName
        self.accessPermission = accessPermission
        self.startTimeStamp = startTimeStamp
    }
    init(blissID blugID:String, location coordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius:CGFloat, duration:Int) {
        self.blguID = blugID
        self.coordinates = coordinates
        self.radiusInMeters = radius
        self.duration = duration
    }
    init(blissID blugID:String, radius:CGFloat, duration:Int) {
        self.blguID = blugID
        self.radiusInMeters = radius
        self.duration = duration
    }
}
```

Here's a screen dump.

 Notice that the values are shown in the variables view; but not in the debugger (nor via println()):

[image]

Is there a remedy or is this another debugger bug?